# Counting objects with Coroutine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

in my project im trying to count the diferent objects and simulate a little animation, for example i have stars in my game, and i want to count the number of stars in the final of the game from 0 trough the number of stars the user got, so i did this:

```
public void youWin()
    {
        audio.Stop ();
        StartCoroutine (activatePanel ());
    }

    IEnumerator activatePanel()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (3f);
        pausePanel2.SetActive (true);
        for (int i = 0; i <= stars; i++) {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.2f);
            starText2.text = i + "";
        }
    }
```

my code worked well for 0.3f on the for loop wait for seconds, but it is too slow, i want it for 0.2f, but something strange happen sometimes it get like a bug and the first number seems to go back, it doesn't count right, someone know what is happening?

Comment: When you say that "it doesn't count right", do you mean that the text is wrong, or just that you feel the timing is off?

Comment: hmm have no idea but i give you a example it happens something like that {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,11,21} at the end of this counting it goes very quick to 11 and then to 21, it does every time

Comment: Perhaps you are calling youWin() multiple times before it has finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It very likely that the `activatePanel` function is being called from another place while it is already running or the script that contains this code is attached to multiple GameObjects and the `activatePanel` is again, being called by another function. You can use flag to stop this from happening.

If the coroutine function is already running, use `yield break;` to break out of it.

```
bool isRunning = false;
IEnumerator activatePanel()
{
    //Exit if already running
    if (isRunning)
    {
        yield break;
    }

    //Not running, now set isRunning to true then run
    isRunning = true;

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);
    pausePanel2.SetActive(true);

    WaitForSeconds waitTime = new WaitForSeconds(0.2f);
    for (int i = 0; i <= stars; i++)
    {
        yield return waitTime;
        starText2.text = i.ToString();
    }

    //Done running, set isRunning to false
    isRunning = false;
}
```

Comment: i ahve that activatePanel associate to just 1 gameobject i don't think that is the problem i already confirme it, if the wait for seconds is a little biger it counts well

Comment: That seems to be the only possible problem. Please use `Debug.Log` in the `for` loop, in the future. It will really help you find this kind of bug in the future.

Comment: yeah watch below, you are right, thank you very much :D

Answer (score 0):

Well i solved it with all of you guys help, actually you all where right, i thaught i was calling the youWin function just 1 time, but i forgot this is unity and i called the youWin inside a trigerEnter function, that means that the object keep enter the triger function and called the youWin function, thank you all here is what i mean with that

**Solved it with the bool entered**

```
public class Victory : MonoBehaviour {

Manager gameManager;
// Use this for initialization
public AudioClip clip;
private AudioSource audio;
public Animator girl;
private bool entered;


void OnTriggerEnter(Collider c)
{
    if (c.gameObject.tag == "Player" && !entered) {
        gameManager.win = true;
        audio.clip = clip;
        audio.Play ();
        gameManager.Ball.GetComponent<MoveBall> ().enabled = true;
        girl.SetBool ("win",true);
        entered = true;
        gameManager.youWin ();
    }
}

void Start () {
    gameManager = GameObject.Find ("GameController").GetComponent<Manager> ();
    audio = GetComponent<AudioSource> ();
    entered = false;

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}
}
```